# The name "num" is not defined

Tags: python

En la tienda de los hermanos Roque es tradición presentar las latas de conserva apiladas triangularmente: en el primer piso una lata, en el segundo piso dos latas, en el tercer piso tres, y así sucesivamente. Por ejemplo, seis latas se ponen así:

[image: latas apiladas]

Los hermanos tienen grandes problemas para realizar los pedidos de latas, ya que no todo número de latas se puede apilar triangularmente. Por ejemplo, 8 latas no se pueden apilar. Crea un programa llamado, en el que dado un número natural introducido por el usuario, comprueba si es adecuado para apilar.
hasta ahora tengo este código

```
def isTriangular(num):
    if (num < 0):
        return False
    
    sum, n = 0, 1 
    while(sum <= num):
     
        sum = sum + n
        if (sum == num):
            return True
        n += 1 
    return False

while True:
    n = int(input("Introduce la altura del triángulo (entero positivo): "))

    if not isTriangular(num):
        print(f"El número {n} no es un triangular")
        continue
        
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1):
            print("*", end="")
        print("")
    break
```

el problema esta aquí

```
    if not isTriangular(num):
        print(f"El número {n} no es un triangular")
        continue
```

porque me arroja el error: the name "num" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

El error te lo dice. `num` no está definiendo en ningún lado. Parece que ahí va el valor que pillas del input

La corrección seria así:

```py
if not isTriangular(n):
```

Comment: ya funciona, muchas gracias

Comment: Cuando una respuesta resuelve el problema, es bueno que la marques como correcta  para que destaque y así tu puedes ayudar a otros a resolver el problema